# Option-delete not working in powerpoint

Tags: ms-office

I'm using microsoft office 2011 and for some reason option-delete doesn't seem to have the standard behavior it usually does. It works fine in word and excel, however.

I don't have another computer to test with — can someone who has powerpoint 2011 see whether option-delete works fine for them too (I want to know whether this is an issue on my end or just microsoft's poor coding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little vague because you don't clarify what you deem to be the standard behaviour of using <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd>.

However, upon my own testing on an iMac with Office 2011, I can confirm that <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd> within MS Word does in fact behave differently than it does in MS PowerPoint. However, I found that it behaves the same way in both Powerpoint and Excel.

More specifically, in MS Word using <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd> will delete the entire word behind the cursor in MS Word, while in Powerpoint and Excel it only deletes a single character, just like it would by pressing the <kbd>delete</kbd> key on its own.

Comment: Standard behavior of option delete would be the way it works in cocoa based apps: that is, it deletes the word. It seems that powerpoint overrides this default behavior, however. Thank you for confirming. I guess now I have to write an applescript or something to replicate that behavior.

Comment: https://kbroman.wordpress.com/2014/02/12/emacs-key-binings-in-ms-wo